# In C language about scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I  grouped  scanf function and named this function **eno** and after calling this function in my **C**  code it did not work perfectly. Where if I use scanf function alone in code it works. So my question is why function did not work?  Here I show a=0 and b=1 .always. :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int eno(int, int);

    int main() {
        int a, b;
        eno(a, b);
        printf("%d  %d", a, b);
    }

   int eno(int j, int k) {
       scanf("%d", &j);
       scanf("%d", &k);
   }
```

Comment: Because `a` and `b` are different variables than `j` and `k`, so passing the addresses of `j` and `k` to `scanf` leaves `a` and `b` unmodified.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to check the return code from scanf to make sure that you read in the number of items that you expected.  So, in your case, if scanf didn't return 1 in both calls, then you didn't get the values assigned.  For example, if I run your program and type in letters instead of numbers, `scanf` wouldn't assign values for you.

Answer (score 6):

`j` and `k` are different objects in memory than `a` and `b`, so writing to `j` and `k` has no effect on `a` and `b`.

For `eno` to modify `a` and `b`, you need to pass *pointers* to `a` and `b` like so:

```
eno( &a, &b );
...
void eno( int *j, int *k ) // use void instead of int here; eno doesn't return a value
{
  scanf( "%d", j ); // no & operator on j or k, they're already pointers
  scanf( "%d", k );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is about a very important fundamental aspect of C.

> C passes all function arguments by **value**

What that means is best described by a simple example:

```
void foo(int x)
{
    x = 42;             // Changes x inside foo but NOT x inside bar
    printf("%d\n", x);  // Prints 42
}

void bar()
{
    int x = 5;
    foo(x);
    printf("%d\n", x);  // Prints 5 
}
```

Output:

```
42
5
```

What is important to understand here is that `x` inside `bar` is **another variable** than `x` inside `foo`. Any change to `x` made inside `foo` will not change `x` in `bar`.

The call `foo(x)` passes **the value of x** to `foo`. So in this case it is the same as `foo(5)`.

To change the value of `x` in `bar` from inside `foo` you'll need to pass a **pointer** to `x`.

That is:

```
void foo(int *x)         // Notice the * - Means that foo receives a pointer to int
{
    *x = 42;             // Notice the * - Change the value of x in bar
    printf("%d\n", *x);  // Notice the * - Read the value of x in bar
}

void bar()
{
    int x = 5;
    foo(&x);      // Notice the & - it takes the address of x so &x is a pointer to x
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

Output:

```
42
42
```

So to make your code work you need to change `eno` so that it receives pointers to int instead of int. Like:

```
int eno(int*, int*);
```

Called like:

```
eno(&a, &b);
```

Comment: ...and then `scanf("%d", j);scanf("%d", k);`

Answer (score 2):

```
eno(a, b);
    ^  ^

int eno(int j, int k)
            ^      ^
```

Values `a` and `b` are copied into `j` and `k` respectively.
When the function `eno` returns, the values have *not* been modified.

---

This is where pointers come into the picture.

```
eno(&a, &b);            // pass the address of a and b
    ^   ^

int eno(int* j, int* k) // j and k now point to a and b respectively.
           ^       ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are passing the values of `a` and `b` to `eno`. You need to pass them by reference as the code below shows. You need to use pointers to pass by reference.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int eno(int *,int*); 

int main(){ 
   int a,b; 
   eno(&a,&b); 
   printf("%d %d",a,b); 
}

int eno(int *j,int *k)
{ 
   scanf("%d",j); 
   scanf("%d",k); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.

for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu17`

Note: other compilers use different options to accomplish the same results.

compiling the posted code results in:

```
gcc -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled.c" 

untitled.c: In function ‘eno’:
untitled.c:17:4: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
    }
    ^

untitled.c: In function ‘main’:

untitled.c:10:9: warning: ‘a’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
         eno(a, b);
         ^~~~~~~~~

untitled.c:10:9: warning: ‘b’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

notice that compiler tells you about three problems with the posted code.

Here is a version of the code that works as desired.

Notice the proper use of passing the addresses of the variables, and the proper declaration of the function: `eno()`

Notice the proper checking for the calls to `scanf()` to assure the operation was successful.

It is a very poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used. I.E. `math.h` and `string.h`

Variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)

in general, function names should be 'active', not 'cryptic'. They should indicate, to the reader of the code, what the function does.

and now, the proposed code, which only fixes the compiler problems, not the more subtle things that would make the code excellent:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <string.h>
//#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

void eno( int *, int * );

int main( void )
{
    int a, b;
    eno( &a, &b);
    printf("%d  %d", a, b);
}

void eno(int *j, int *k) 
{
    if( scanf("%d", j) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf to read the variable j failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if( scanf("%d", k) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf to read the variable k failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
```